# Is there a way to combine a potentially unlimited set of lists?

Tags: r, for-loop, rbind

The following script pulls some specific country data from an API from the UN. I created a for loop to help with cases where the user would like to pull multiple countries from the database. The problem I am struggling with is after the for loop where I combine the lists from the "data" element within the "response" vector (response$data). I am currently using rbind() to group the multiple lists but would like to find a solution to account for a potentially unlimited amount of lists without having to manually write out each one.

```
library(jsonlite)
library(httr)

base_url <- "https://population.un.org/dataportalapi/api/v1/data"

locationlist <- list("528","40","620") # example list of country codes

target <- list()
response <- list()

for (i in locationlist) {
  
  target[[i]] <- paste0(base_url, "/indicators/",65,"/locations/",i,"/start/",2000,"/end/",2019) # url
  response[[i]] <- fromJSON(target[[i]]) # call API
  
}

# Here's the main issue :
df <- rbind(response[[1]]$data,response[[2]]$data,response[[3]]$data) # combine lists
```

I have tried incorporating the rbind() within the for loop instead without much success.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please read and apply ["What is the proper way to approach Stack Overflow as someone totally new to programming?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254572/11107541) Once you do that, [you don't need to tell us that you are new to `X`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296391/11107541).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `response` element is a `list` and we need to only extract the `data` component.  So, loop over the `response` (which is a `list`), use either `[[` or `$` to extract the 'data' part, which returns a `list` of `data.frame`s, that can be `rbind`ed with `do.call`

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(response, `[[`, "data"))
```

-output

```
> dim(out)
[1] 60 32
```

---

Or use `tidyverse`

```
library(purrr) # version 1.0.0
library(dplyr)
out <- map(response, pluck, "data") %>%
   list_rbind
#or may also use
out <- map_dfr(response, pluck, "data")
```

---

Instead of doing this in a `for` loop, it can be done with `lapply` or `map`

```
library(stringr)
urls <- str_c(base_url, "/indicators/",65,"/locations/",
     locationlist,"/start/",2000,"/end/",2019)
out <- map_dfr(urls, ~ fromJSON(.x) %>% 
            pluck("data"))
> dim(out)
[1] 60 32
```

out <- map(